# PHP - Text preprocess on text mining slow process

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, text-mining

i make a text preprocess on text mining with large database,, i want make a camus data from all article on database into array, but it take to long process.

```
$multiMem   = memory_get_usage();
$xstart = microtime(TRUE);
$word = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_content");
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $word = $word."".$data['article'];
}

$preprocess = new preprocess($word);
$word= $preprocess->preprocess($word);
print_r($kata);

$xfinish = microtime(TRUE);
```

> here is my class preprocess

```
class preprocess {

  var $teks;

  function preprocess($teks){
  /*start process segmentation*/
  $teks = trim($teks);

  //menghapus tanda baca
  $teks = str_replace("'", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace("-", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace(")", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace("(", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace("=", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace(".", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace(",", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace(":", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace(";", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace("!", "", $teks);
  $teks = str_replace("?", "", $teks);

  //remove HTML tags
  $teks = strip_tags($teks);
  $teks = preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $teks);
  /*end proses segmentation*/

  /*start case folding*/
  $teks = strtolower($teks);

  $teks = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $teks);
  /*end case folding*/

  /*start of tokenizing*/
  $teks = explode(" ", $teks);

  /*end of tokenizing*/

  /*start of filtering*/
  //stopword
  $file = file_get_contents('stopword.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
  $stopword = explode("\n", $file);

  //remove stopword
  $teks = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$stopword).')\b/','',$teks);

  /*end of filtering*/

  /*start of stemming*/
  require_once('stemming.php');
  foreach($teks as $t => $value){
    $teks[$t] = stemming($value);
  }
  /*end of stemming*/

  $teks = array_filter($teks);
  $teks = array_values($teks);

  return $teks;
 }
}
```

anyone have any idea to make fast process on my program? pls help
thanks for advance

Comment: First compare the timing of processing of `PHP` and `mysql` queries and then update which is taking long time.

Comment: for all preprocess in microtime take '659.52643299103' with '2210' array length from return class

Comment: Potentially excessive memory usage. I'd do this in the `while` loop with every single article, avoiding repeating `file_get_contents` etc.

Comment: it keep take long respond, i use single array, ex: `$stopword = array ('word1', 'word2', ....)`.. i convert manually all **stopword.txt** to array

Comment: Update your code with what you have now.

Comment: Also you should measure the execution time on a couple of blocks. Eg. how long it taks the query, how long it takes the $word concatenation, how long it takes the stemming, how long it takes each str_replace and each preg_replace. So we know which one is having the bad timing ;)

Comment: wait ill put `microtime` in every function

Comment: u can check my code [here](https://pastebin.com/Q7XsrXqM)

Comment: if you use `$teks = preg_replace('/[0-9,\(\)\-\=\.\,\;\!\?]+/', '', $teks);` you can skip the `$teks = str_replace(array('(','-',')',',','.','=',';','!','?'), '', $teks);`

Comment: @bluehipy i use first option...
then here result time all process:
total 1111.5031321049...
sql 1111.4225699902...
stemtotal 1.5020370483398E-5...
preprocesstotal 0.024682998657227...
stopword 0.30824208259583...
it mean something wrong in my mysql?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139767/discussion-between-bluehipy-and-rizaldy-setiawan-h).

Answer (score 1):

Ther are a couple of things that might be  improoved...

1. After building up the `$word` you could free the query result `$sql` and the `data`

   ```
   $word = '';
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_content");
   while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     $word = $word . $data['article'];
   }
   mysql_free_result($sql);
   unset($sql, $data);
   ```
2. This block:

   ```
   $teks = str_replace("'", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace("-", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace(")", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace("(", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace("=", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace(".", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace(",", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace(":", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace(";", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace("!", "", $teks);
   $teks = str_replace("?", "", $teks);
   ```

can be written like this:

```
    $teks = str_replace(array('(','-',')',',','.','=',';','!','?'), '', $teks);
```

3. since you later in the code replace the numbers with a regular expression, you could add numbers in the upper `str_replace` call, or add the upper chars to the `preg_replace`

   ```
   $teks = str_replace(array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','(','-',')',',','.','=',';','!','?'), '', $teks);
   ```

   OR

   ```
   $teks = preg_replace('/[0-9,\(\)\-\=\.\,\;\!\?]+/', '', $teks);
   ```
4. `$teks = strip_tags($teks);` should be enough. If it isn'y then use just the `preg_replace` following, since it's doing kind of the same thing.
5. use `file` insted of the file_get_contents`followed by the`explode`since the`file`returns an array directly. Also there is no need to explode the $teks`

   ```
      $stopword = file('stopword.txt');
      array_walk($stopword, function(&$item1){
        $item1 = '/\b' . $item1 . '\b/';
      });
      $teks = preg_replace($stopword, '', $teks);
   ```
6. Generally don't use `""` since the processor will try to evaluate the content and that takes longer.
7. If the `stopword.txt` list is not changing it is better and faster to have it in the code as an array directly then accessing the file system to read it.

Comment: i change a little of my code with ur suggestions, but it still take long respond.. pls check and help me [link](https://pastebin.com/Q7XsrXqM)

Comment: also i change **stopword.txt** with a single array

Comment: i use NA algorithm for indonesian language, [link](https://pastebin.com/eSPhZQfm)